# Mule ESB: Can not start application in standalone server

Tags: mule, esb

I have only worked with the studio to this point.  I have a working flow that was tested in the studio (Windows) and I want to put it on a stand alone server (Linux)

So I downloaded the EE standalone and installed it, and can run the console from it

```
./startup.sh
Please enter the desired port for Mule [Default 7777]:

Starting MMC, please wait...

[11-06 16:40:50] INFO  AbstractBundlePersistenceManager [http-bio-8585-exec-11]: cachename=versionBundleCache[ConcurrentCache@3e585378], elements=30, usedmemorykb=5, maxmemorykb=8192, access=381, miss=30
[11-06 16:41:50] INFO  AbstractBundlePersistenceManager [http-bio-8585-exec-11]: cachename=defaultBundleCache[ConcurrentCache@204bdc52], elements=175, usedmemorykb=345, maxmemorykb=8192, access=1270, miss=175
...
...
...
INFO  2014-11-06 16:47:50,832 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleSharedDomainClassLoader: Using domain dir /ee/mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1/mule-enterprise-3.5.2/domains/default for domain default
./startup.sh: line 135: 25780 Terminated              tail -f logs/catalina.out  (wd: /ee/mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1/mmc-3.5.2-HF1/apache-tomcat-7.0.52)
./startup.sh: line 135: 26250 Terminated              tail -f mule-enterprise-3.5.2/logs/mule_ee.log

Mule Started
Mule running as PID=27417
Tomcat and MMC running as PID=25801
Finished starting Mule and MMC. Please go to http://localhost:8585/mmc-3.5.2-HF1
[root@x240perf2 mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1]#
```

.. and I can display the status:

```
./status.sh
MMC is running as PID=25801.
Mule Enterprise Edition is running as PID=27417.
```

and I can bring up the console at the following browser address:  http://x.x.x.x:8585/mmc-3.5.2-HF1/index.jsp#dashboard

So now I want to deploy an app (the one I tested in the studio).  So I use the following  link as a guide:

```
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deploying+Mule+Applications
```

From there the instuctions state:

```
Navigate to the folder that contains your copy of Mule ESB Standalone, then paste the application’s zip file into the apps folder.
```

So I do the following:

```
[root@x240perf2 apps]# pwd
/ee/mmc-distribution-mule-console-bundle-3.5.2-HF1/mule-enterprise-3.5.2/apps
[root@x240perf2 apps]#
[root@x240perf2 apps]# ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxrwx.  3 benchmarking games 4096 Nov  6 17:03 .
drwxrwxr-x. 14 benchmarking games 4096 Oct 23 16:10 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  2 benchmarking games 4096 Nov  6 14:44 default
-rw-r--r--.  1 root         root    88 Nov  6 17:03 default-anchor.txt
[root@x240perf2 apps]#
[root@x240perf2 apps]# cp /home/app/dm.zip .
[root@x240perf2 apps]#
[root@x240perf2 apps]# ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxrwx.  4 benchmarking games 4096 Nov  6 17:04 .
drwxrwxr-x. 14 benchmarking games 4096 Oct 23 16:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  6 root         root  4096 Nov  6 17:04 dm
drwxrwxrwx.  2 benchmarking games 4096 Nov  6 14:44 default
-rw-r--r--.  1 root         root    88 Nov  6 17:03 default-anchor.txt
```

As you can see, after I copied the dm.zip file to the apps directory, it was turned into a directory

```
[root@x240perf2 dm]# ls
classes  lib       mule-app.properties  mule-deploy.properties
docroot  META-INF  mule-config.xml      portfolio_schema_to_port_schema.grf
[root@x240perf2 dm]#
```

However, I can find no confirmation that it is running.  There is nothing in the 'Deployments' section of the console.

Also, the documentation said that it is deployed automatically (I guess that is why it has unzipped into a directory, but the app does not work, and the documentation also says:

```
In the command line, Mule notifies you that it has deployed the application.
```

.. and the documentation gives the following as an example:

```
**********************************************************************
* - - + APPLICATION + - -            * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* my_first_application                * DEPLOYED           *
* default                             * DEPLOYED           *
**********************************************************************

INFO  2012-10-29 15:40:57,516 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

So how do I get to the command line.  After I perform the startup.sh, it eventually stops and says Mule is running.  After I copy the zip file it unzips it, but I do not know which command line the documentation is referring

What command line is this referring to, and what am I missing?

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Could this be because I exported from a COmmunity Edition Studio, and exported to a Enterprise Edition Standalone server ?

Comment: to my knowledge the application is deployed and what is the exact issue? Do you need the application listed in the console? or some thing else. I see from your log info the application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

You can search the logs files in MULE_HOME/logs/mule_ee.log

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you are referring to which shows the deployment status is not in the command line. Mule stores the deployment status in the log file `mule_ee.log`. Open the log file to check the status - `MULE_HOME/logs/mule_ee.log`.

Note: I am using the latest version Mule 3.8.0.